# Remove text and number from text

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have many text:

```
var one = 'this_is_first_text#test=4';
var two = 'second_text#test=2';
var three = 'next_text#test=243';
var four = 'last_text_for_this#test=44';
```

how can i remove for this **#test=X** ?

I can remove only text:

```
one.replace('#test=', '');
```

but hot to remove number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) can take a regular expression as an argument. Thus, you can use the following:

```
one.replace(/#test=\d+/, '')
```

`\d+` will match one or more digits.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/srUTw/)**.

Answer (score 4):

```
one = one.slice(0, one.indexOf('#'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U3PU2/

Answer (score 3):

```
 one = one.split("#"); one=one[0];
```

Comment: No problem, and you could actually condense it to be: `one = one.split("#")[0];`, right? But if you wanted to be safe, you would check to see that the length of `one` (after the split) is greater than 0...

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex ?

```
one.replace(/\#test\=.*/,'');
```